# Ionic AlertController and HTML code

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi want something like this and also assigned the css to each div and address block. Is it possible???

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Contact Us',
            subTitle: `
                <div class="address-block pp-notes-row">

                    <address></address>
                </div>
            `,
            buttons: ['OK'],
            cssClass: `
                .alert-wrapper {
                    width: 100%
                }

                .address-block {
                    text-align: left;
                }
            `
        });
        alert.present();
```

Comment: Try using a popover for custom html/css ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do like this

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: '<h1 class="c-no-margin winner-alert-title">Congratulations!</h1>',
  message: '<div>' +
  '<p class="c-no-margin">You are the WINNER, now please submit your details to your favourite celebrity and get video call.</p>' +
  '</div>',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Select Celebrity',
      handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.push("CelebrityList");
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know you could do this

Comment: Has chrome changed its policy, my html gets stripped out and I receive: `WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

Comment: @santeko:  the warning is not coming from the browser, it's generated by angular on top of which ionic is built. You might get it when your HTML has ampersands, entities, and other characters/tags that can be exploited.

Comment: It's a very easy solution. Thank you.

Comment: This does not seems to be working anymore :/